# Migrate existing Kentico database to Azure SQL - collation mismatch

Tags: database, azure, collation, kentico

We currently have a SQL Server Kentico database that we are looking to move into Azure SQL. The current database has a collation type of Latin1_General_CI_AS (Kentico default) and our Azure SQL master db is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (Azure default).

We initially just imported it into a new Azure db which seemed to work fine until Kentico executes any queries that involve comparing strings between system tables and the Kentico database. e.g. the wizard when creating a Custom Table within Kentico and trying to select an existing database table. It was then that we realised the mismatch of the collation between master and our Kentico database.

Is there any way of changing the collation type on the Kentico database or importing across our Kentico content, etc into a new database?

We have tried the obvious - `ALTER DATABASE <name> COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` but that won't work due to a number of objects that give the error: "The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it."

I'm hoping not to have to start a new database and manually migrate all our content and customisations into a new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've solved this myself :)

1. Used Site Export to export all objects from my working site
2. Created a new empty Azure SQL database with the standard Azure collation
3. Changed my web app's web.config to point to the new empty database
4. Run web app and went through the database wizard to setup the base Kentico objects in the new empty database
5. Created a new site via importing my exported site from Step 1

Now I have my full site, etc in a new database with the correct collation type.

Comment: We're having the same problem right now and looks like this is the only solution.

Comment: Just an update, the site export did not work for us due to the same collation issue.

Comment: When I did the site export it was from when the CMS that was not on Azure and so didn't have the collation mismatch. It was using a local SQL instance with the master database set to the same collation as Kentico.

Answer (score 1):

I had this painful issue too. I'm not sure why Kentico changed the collation to default to that, but the good thing is that Azure now allows you to set the collation when you're creating a new database. You just need to type in 'Latin1_General_CI_AS' in the collation box.

Comment: I didn't have troubles creating the database within Azure as Latin1_General_CI_AS - the problem was that the Azure database server master database is automatically set as SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and the issue arises when Kentico executes queries that includes tables in the master database.